# Display Image In SharePoint that Requires Basic Authentication

Tags: php, html, sharepoint

I have an image, which is actually a graph that is dynamically generated, that is hosted on another server (that I don't have access to).  That site requires basic authentication before displaying the image. If you have not already logged in, you'll be presented a login box (basic authentication, not forms authentication).  The login credentials are always the same - they won't be different based on what user is logged into SharePoint.

The image can be accessed from https://site.com/image.php?id=1336

I want to embed this image in SharePoint.  It doesn't need to directly embedded.  I'm willing to write a simple page, host it outside SharePoint, and embed that if it make more sense (although a single embedded solution is generally easier to manage).  The solution needs to work with most modern browsers (for example, you can use the URL https://user:password@site.com/image.php?id=1336 in Chrome, but it doesn't work with IE).

I've done a fair amount of searching around, but haven't found a solution that fits the need (and that I've got the brain power to follow).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider this http://camelotphptools.codeplex.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using cUrl this would be pretty simple:

```
$host = 'http://path-to-your-site.com/image.php?id=1336'; //site
$username = 'username'; //basic auth username
$password = 'password'; //basic auth password
$process = curl_init($host); //initiate the host request
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: image/png'); //png?
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // 1 for incldue header in output, 0 for not
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); //the auth request
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //how long will we wait 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 0); //not a post request
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //return as a string or print immediately?
$return = curl_exec($process); //the returned image
curl_close($process); //end your curl request
//do something with $return
```

Comment: How does the path to your site look like?